# Thunderbird filling up GBs of disk space

Tags: thunderbird, disk-usage

I have dedicated 5GB of space for my home folder. I have 6 email boxes and when I add them to Thunderbird it downloads everything from them and fills up the whole home folder (3-4GB). This is unacceptable. I need to be able to limit its cache, I don't need all of the emails downloaded, just the new ones.
I tried setting lower space at `Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Network & Disk space` but it does not work, it again downloads 3-4GB of messages...

How do I limit it to 100-200MB?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't limit to 100-200 MB, but you can change the settings to only download the newest messages.

Go to `Edit -> Account Settings -> Synchronization & Storage`
 under the "Disk Space" heading, select
 "Synchronize Most recent" & "Don't Download Messages Larger Than", then input your desired values.

Comment: However, checking this option doesn't seem to clear the mails that were already downloaded?